# Which has a high melting point, cocoa powder or cocoa butter?

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, melting-point

I have been doing some research into chocolate, and after looking at the chemical compositions of cocoa butter and cocoa powder, struggled to determine which had a formula/structure that would have a higher melting point. 
Which has a higher melting point, natural cocoa powder or cocoa butter?

(For those unfamiliar with the differences between cocoa powder and cocoa butter, here is some helpful information:
Cocoa powder: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_solids
Cocoa butter:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_butter
Composition of both:
https://www.icco.org/faq/61-physical-and-chemical-information-on-cocoa/106-physical-and-chemical-information-on-cocoa-beans-butter-mass-and-powder.html
Thanks!)

Comment: If you hold a piece of chocolate, containing cocoa butter, in your hand, does it melt ? Yes, it does.  If you do the same with cocoa powder, does it melt ? No, it does not.

Comment: I rather doubt cocoa solids actually melt on heating, they are rather more likely to decompose

Comment: None of them have melting point  For their behaviour see comments above.